Why updating state rebuild all widgets
Why setting state of a sibling widget update all the widgets specially custom painter as i make its own stateless widget it should not be effected coz i haven't pass any param from parent.

run sample on Zapp

https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zxke06w7xkf0?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  return runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  Offset mousePosition = Offset.zero;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              const MyBackground(),
              MouseRegion(
                onHover: (event) {
                  mousePosition = event.position;
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
              Text('X: ${mousePosition.dx}, Y: ${mousePosition.dy}'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyBackground extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyBackground({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox.expand(
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: MyPainter(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.blue,
  ];

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    debugPrint('paint');

    final randumNumber = Random().nextInt(colors.length);

    final paint = Paint()..color = colors[randumNumber];
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height), paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}



return RepaintBoundary(child: SizedBox.expand(child: CustomPaint(painter: MyPainter())) );

OMG! its this simple thanks it worked now need to understand what happen with 'RepaintBoundary'

sure, your welcome
